# Can't install Apache::Template on Debian

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, perl, template

When I try to install this module via cpan:  cpan -i Apache::Template

I get an error "512, won't make".  This behavior is the same on Debian Lenny or Squeeze.

Any ideas on how to get it to build?

Answer (score 0):

First install Apache::ModuleConfig:

```
 cpan -i Apache::ModuleConfig
```

Comment: Warning: Cannot install Apache::ModuleConfig, don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these versions of Debian use mod_perl 2. The version of Apache::Template on CPAN only works with mod_perl version 1. You can get a version that works from http://www.modperlcookbook.org/~geoff/modules/experimental/